# UDP socket errno in iOS

Tags: ios, sockets, udp

I am creating a UDP socket, and attempting to send to an existing server in the code below:

```
struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));  
servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;              
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER IP ADDRESS GOES HERE);
servAddr.sin_port   = htons(port);

int testSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

unsigned char byteData;
int sent;
unsigned int servSize = sizeof(servAddr);

if((sent = sendto(testSock, &byteData, 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddr,  (socklen_t)&servSize)) < 0){
    NSLog(@"Error sending to server: %d %d", errno, sent);
}
```

Every time "sendto" returns -1, and errno is set to 63. I have never encountered this error before.

I can say with complete confidence that there is nothing wrong with the server, or the IP address or port provided. It has to be client-side.

Comment: Instead of working directly on this level, I would suggest taking a look at [Cocoa AsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) as it makes things a lot less complicated.

Comment: Instead of just printing the error number, consider using [`strerror`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a text describing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

63 is 'filename too long'. In this case it is the sockaddr that appears too long to the kernel, and that is because you are passing a pointer as the length, instead of the actual length. The final parameter to sendto() isn't a pointer, it is a value. Remove the '&'.

Comment: ...and the fact that you're trying to cast a pointer to a length type (`(socklen_t)&servSize`) is a red flag that you're passing the wrong datatype.